# How to display 'Mistake Contribution %' in a column out of total mistakes?

Tags: info-visualisation, data-tables

There are a total number of mistakes X, now I want to create a column for showing distribution for the total mistakes X, what will be the shorter name or better way to represent this?

Note: Total mistake will not be 100%, it can be 'x%',e.g. if a user has done 94% things right, I want to explain the distribution for his 6%

[image: Mistake Distribution]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numeric values should be right-aligned in their own columns for easy scanning and comparison. Graphics help.

[image: Pie chart and table]

Answer (score 0):

A percentage is defined as "any proportion or share in relation to a whole". I'd say that makes the "out of total mistakes" parenthetical redundant.

In your question, you use the term "distribution" which I think would work nicely for the column header.

> ## Mistakes
>
> **Type**   **Distribution**
>   ...
>   ...

Answer (score 0):

I'd move 'Mistake' to a header, and name the second column [Frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_(statistics)). You could add something like '(% of total)' to the header, though if you add a total row at the end with 100% it's also quite obvious.

```
Mistakes

Type       |   Frequency
------------------------
A          |   88   (3%)
B          |   29   (1%)
C          |   60   (2%)
no mistake |        94%
------------------------
Total      | 2900 (100%)
```

Comment: sorry, my question was not clear enough(edited the question) total mistake can be 'X%', e.g. If a user has done 94% things right, I want to explain the distribution for his 6%

Comment: I don't understand. If it's a total, why isn't it 100%? Perhaps you should add a little more example data?

Comment: edited my comment

Comment: I'm still not understanding it completely, but perhaps it then make sense to add an extra row (at the end or beginning) for that 94%? See the update.